# How to align text (right/center) on MobileSafari iPad1

Tags: html, css, ipad, mobile-safari

I'm trying to align the text and placeholder of an input field center or right. This works in all browsers using the `text-align` property, but fails in mobile Safari on iPad 1. The text itself is aligned, but the placeholder text stays left side all the time.

See the fiddle: [input-text-alignment](http://jsfiddle.net/tzWWM/)

How can I align that placeholder text on iPad 1?

Answer (score 0):

```
form input {
    height: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid  gray;
    text-align: center;

}

form {
    margin:auto;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: That changes only the position of the input element itself. It does not affect the placement of the placeholder text.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an iPad to test it on, however since Safari uses the web-kit engine you might try the following code:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder{
text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: That was one of my first shots, unfortunately, it does not do the job. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the display properties. this may solve your problem like this `display: inline-block;` to your input element.

Comment: The display property does not affect the placement of the placeholder. Tried block, inline-block and inline.

Comment: Did you try display: table-cell;